# how do we display an image/color in lua

Tags: lua, embedded-linux, lua-5.2

I am having this problem, and I am not able to figure out the solution.
I wish to display an image in some window if possible(not necessary tough), and then move it across the page by sending events from keyboard.

The problem is I can't use LÖVE framework, as we can't integrate it into our setup.
So I would require the Lua api's to do so.

Is anyone here aware about it? Also do I have to install some kind of extra library to support color and image operations?

Thanks for sharing the knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Lua is quite a bare-bones language to start with, so there is no built in image support whatsoever. But this also goes for almost all other programing languages, image support is typically something contained in supplementary libraries.

You need to install some library providing GUI functionality (like [IUP](http://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/iup/)), or use an application integrating Lua with graphical libraries (like [murgaLua](http://www.murga-projects.com/murgaLua/index.html), [Löve](http://love2d.org/), ...)

From the tags you attached to your question it seems that you're using an embedded platform. It might be useful for people to know which, in order to provide more useful answers.